# Testing an executable with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I created an executable with Swift via `swift package init --type executable` and would now like to write a few tests for it. This doesn't appear to be an issue at all for library packages, in that case Swift also populates the `Tests` directory with a tests module which runs nicely via `swift test`. For an executable only an empty `Tests` directory is created.

On trying to run tests for my executable from within Xcode or via `swift test` I'm running into linker issues though that seem to specify that Swift is unable to link the contents of my main.swift to the tests. I'm not sure what I can do here. I've tried playing around within Xcode to create new framework targets to be linked, but none of that would be picked up by `swift test` anyways as far as I can tell. I didn't manage to get it working via Xcode either. The following is the output from `swift test`.

```
Compile Swift Module 'swifttest' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/swifttest
Compile Swift Module 'swifttestTests' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/swifttestPackageTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/swifttestPackageTests
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TF9swifttest3fooFT_SS", referenced from:
      __TFFC14swifttestTests14SwifttestTests7testFooFT_T_u0_KzT_SS in swifttestTests.swift.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/kilian/Desktop/swifttest/.build/debug.yaml test
```

These are the contents of my files for reference. It's a minimal example project.

**main.swift**

```
public func foo() -> String {
    return "bar"
}

print(foo())
```

**swifttestTests.swift**

```
import Foundation
import XCTest
import swifttest

class SwifttestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testFoo() {
        XCTAssertEqual("bar", foo())
    }
}
```

**Directory Layout**

```
.
├── Package.swift
├── Sources
│   └── main.swift
└── Tests
    └── swifttestTests
        └── swifttestTests.swift
```

Answer (score 8):

Whilst not exactly a solution to not being able to test an executable I was made aware of a workaround. The basic idea is to move more or less everything into a second module inside the same project and minimizing the executable target to a call to an entry function.

A basic structure following the given example would look like this:

```
.
├── Package.swift
├── Sources
│ └── swifttest
│ │ └── main.swift
│ └── SwiftTestLib
│     └── foo.swift
└── Tests
    └── SwiftTestLibTests
        └── SwiftTestLibTests.swift
```

This makes it necessary however to specify the targets in the `Package.swift`.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "swifttest",
  targets: [
    Target(name: "swifttest", dependencies: ["SwiftTestLib"]),
    Target(name: "SwiftTestLib", dependencies: []),
  ],
  dependencies: []
)
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue you did, dont understand how to add a new module, every package or framework I try to add to the main package is magically deleted.