# How to list Swift unit test cases on Ubuntu?

Tags: swift, swift4

When I run

```
% swift test -l
```

on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, I always get

```
error: malformed
```

What is the correct way to list Swift unit test cases on Ubuntu?

Swift Version:

```
Swift version 4.0.2 (swift-4.0.2-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: how have you done it so far? this question is too broad

Comment: Like I described: I run the command `% swift test -l`. This *should* return a list of available test cases, but it doesn't.

Comment: so it would normally so you must of done something wrong, but we cannot see that and tell you what it is unless you show what you have

Comment: This looks related (maybe): https://stackoverflow.com/q/42767700/2227743