# How to test a class in a Swift package?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm currently trying to understand the mechanism of importing dependencies in a Swift package and I've run into an issue with tests. Hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong. I'm going to describe the problem step-by-step so that you could easily reproduce it.

So I'm creating a new Swift package using `swift package init --type executable`. This command creates the basic Swift package structure:

```
Artems-MacBook-Pro:SwiftExample artem$ swift package init --type executable
Creating executable package: SwiftExample
Creating Package.swift
Creating README.md
Creating .gitignore
Creating Sources/
Creating Sources/SwiftExample/main.swift
Creating Tests/
Creating Tests/LinuxMain.swift
Creating Tests/SwiftExampleTests/
Creating Tests/SwiftExampleTests/SwiftExampleTests.swift
Creating Tests/SwiftExampleTests/XCTestManifests.swift
```

The package itself is called `SwiftExample`. As you can see the command also creates an example of a unit test case (`SwiftExampleTests.swift`).

Then I create a simple class called `Car.swift` and put it into the `Sources/SwiftExample/Classes/` directory:

```swift
// Sources/SwiftExample/Classes/Car.swift
class Car {
    init() {
        print("I'm a car!")
    }
}
```

In the `main.swift` file I can create an instance of the Car class and everything works pretty much fine:

```swift
// Sources/SwiftExample/main.swift
print("Hello, world!")

let car = Car()
```

The output would be:

```
Hello, world!
I'm a car!
```

But the problem is I cannot use this class in my test file. For example, I'm trying to create an instance of the `Car` class in the `testExample()` function of the `SwiftExampleTests.swift` file:

```swift
import XCTest
import class Foundation.Bundle

@testable import SwiftExample

final class SwiftExampleTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() throws {

        let car = Car()

        <other code goes here>
   }

   <other code goes here>
}
```

As you can see I've imported the module itself using the keyword `@testable`. But when I run `swift test` command I'm getting this weird error:

```
Compile Swift Module 'SwiftExample' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'SwiftExampleTests' (2 sources)
Linking ./.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/SwiftExample
/Users/artem/Playgrounds/SwiftExample/Tests/SwiftExampleTests/SwiftExampleTests.swift:9:13: warning: initialization of immutable value 'car' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
        let car = Car()
        ~~~~^~~
        _
Linking ./.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/SwiftExamplePackageTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/SwiftExamplePackageTests
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_$S12SwiftExample3CarCACycfC", referenced from:
      _$S17SwiftExampleTestsAAC04testB0yyKF in SwiftExampleTests.swift.o
  "_$S12SwiftExample3CarCMa", referenced from:
      _$S17SwiftExampleTestsAAC04testB0yyKF in SwiftExampleTests.swift.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: terminated(1): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/artem/Playgrounds/SwiftExample/.build/debug.yaml test output:
```

I'm certainly doing something wrong here but I can't find any information on the matter in the official docs. Does somebody know what's happening here and how to fix that?

Comment: FYI: `_$S12SwiftExample3CarCACycfC` and `_$S12SwiftExample3CarCMa` are the [mangled variants](https://www.swiftdemangler.com/) of `SwiftExample.Car.__allocating_init() -> SwiftExample.Car` and `type metadata accessor for SwiftExample.Car`, respectively.

Comment: What does your `Package.swift` file look like?

Comment: @Alexander here is it: https://pastebin.com/KM0N2RUD

Comment: I didn't change anything there so it is the default Package.swift after executing `swift package init --type executable`

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what's causing this. As a debugging measure, try making `Car` and its initializer `public`, see if that changes anything.

Comment: Last I checked, SPM simply couldn't run unit tests against an executable. I don't believe it's changed. Quite annoying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing an executable with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767700/testing-an-executable-with-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue won't reproduce anymore in the latest Swift version. The `Car` class can be imported and the `swift test` command won't fail.

For the record, my current `swift --version` output is:

```
swift-driver version: 1.45.2 Apple Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx12.0
```